# adt eclipse and libGDX android launcher not working

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, adt

I'm using google's adt with eclipse and I installed gradle. I created a libGDX project and changed nothing in the code. The desktop launcher works fine and I see a red background with the bad logic games logo.

However when I try and run the android launcher the emulator gives me following message:

`the application my-gdx-game (process com.my gdx.game.android) has stopped unexpectedly. please try again`

Comment: Google has cut the support for Eclipse. As far as I know. So get into the Android Studio. It is very easy to import to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use libGDX with the default android emulator.

Use on your real phone (if you have one) or try Bluestacks, this is the best android emulator i know so far.
http://www.bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately  I have been trying to fix same problem for 2 days. But I have found finally that problem. I know this Question is old. But When someone search the problem by google then Maybe they can solve it.
The solution;

- Right click on YourProjectGame-android
- Click to Properties and Java Built Path
- Source(click on Add Folder and select all folder except \bin)
- Order and Export(Click on Select all)
- Apply and Ok
  AND.....
- Create your emulator device
- Creation Detail is;
- CPU/ABI= Intel Atom(x86_64)
- Emulation Options=Use Host GPU

  - And Other    options are depends on you